# Trying to get the current user name from my database in firebase but getting undefined instead

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

If I wanted to get the email adress of my current user it is working but for the name of the other data it is not.
Maybe I don't save data correctly in the firebase or I don't know.

*This is my registration in the database:*

```js
document.getElementById('intrebari').addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const email = document.getElementById('Email');
  const nume = document.getElementById('NumeUtilizator');
  const parola = document.getElementById('ParolaInregistrare');
  const conf = document.getElementById('ConfirmareParola');
  const gen = document.getElementById('gen');
  const platforma = document.getElementById('platforma');
  const on_off = document.getElementById('on_off');
  const timp = document.getElementById('timp');

  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, parola.value)
    .catch(function (error) {
      firebase.database().ref('utilizatori').push({
        Nume: nume.value,
        Email: email.value,
        Parola: parola.value,
        Gen: gen.value,
        Platforma: platforma.value,
        Online_Offline: on_off.value,
        Timp: timp.value,
        userID: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
        email: firebase.auth().currentUser.email

      }).then((cred) => {

        location.reload();
      });
      console.log(error.message);
      if (error.message === "The email address is badly formatted.") {
        $("#eroare_inregistrare").show().text("Introdu un email valid");
      }

      if (error.message === "The email address is already in use by another account.") {
        $("#eroare_inregistrare").show().text("Acest email este deja folosit.")
      }
    })
})
```

*And this is where i want to get my current user`s name:*

```js
function get() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
        if (user) {
            console.log(user.Nume);
        }
        else {
            console.log("no user is sign in");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: put code in the question, not pictures of code

Comment: you are trying to save a new user to your database in your catch function. This function gets called when an error occurs. You need to do this inside your then function